# How to transform JSON keys into value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to transform following format
JSON:

```
{
    id1: value1,
    id2: value2
    id3: value3,
    ...
}
```

into

```
[    
    { id: 'id1', value: 'value1' },
    { id: 'id2', value: 'value2' },
    { id: 'id3', value: 'value3' },
    ...
]
```

What would be fast and convenient?
Is there any way we can use underscore.js for this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` method provided by underscore.

```
  var input = {
    "id1": "value1",
    "id2": "value2"
  };

  var output = _.map(input, function (value, key) {
    return {id: key, value: value};
  });
```

Comment: Yes. Actully i am using underscore and it works..Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({id:k, value:obj[k]}));
```

no underscore required ;-)  If you're not using babel or something similar you might need to write:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) { return {id:k, value:obj[k]};});
```

Answer (score 1):

User the following:

```
var arr = [];

var obj = {
    id1: "42",
    id2: "hello",
    id3: 6,
}

for (var i in obj) {
    arr.push({id: i, value: obj[i]});
}
```

Alternatively:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function(value, index) {
   return {id: value, value: obj[value]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to ensure that you are only adding the keys that are directly set on `obj`:

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push({ id: key, value: object[value] });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just `parse` it using:

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

If that doesn't produce the desired result then just iterate through your string and manually add in the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore, you could do this with the map method:

```
var obj = {
    id1: 'value1',
    id2: 'value2',
    id3: 'value3',
}

//with underscore, transforming the array
_.map(obj, function(value,key){
    return({
    id: key.toString(),
    value: value
  })
})
//obj = Object {id1: "value1", id2: "value2", id3: "value3"}
```

Here's a jsfiddle to test

[Underscore map](https://jsfiddle.net/tbsgc94r/)

Answer (score 0):

There is simple and efficient way to do it with underscore lib.
Please try it:

```
_.map({id1: value1, id2: value2}, function(value, key) {
    return {id: key, value: value};
});
```